# How do I prevent Maven including certain dependencies in deployable war?

Tags: spring, security, maven, dependency-management

I'm migrating an application that uses Spring security 3.0 to Spring security 3.1.

I have been getting an error about incorrect schema being referenced:

```
SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class    
org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.BeanDefinitionParsingException: Configuration    
problem: You must use a 3.0 schema with Spring Security 3.0.(2.0 or 3.1 versions are not  
valid) Please update your schema declarations to the 3.0.3 schema (spring-security- 
3.0.3.xsd).
Offending resource: ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/security-context.xml]
```

When I look in /lib I see a number of jars that are 3.1 versions are duplicated as 3.0 versions. I suspect this is what is causing the error above.

When I look at the dependency tree of the pom.xml using the Eclipse Maven plugin, I can see where the earlier versions are being referenced (eg spring-security-acl depends on several 3.0 jars) but they are marked as 'omitted for conflict with...'. Does that not mean they should be omitted from the built war file?

I've tried explicitly naming 3.1 versions of those files at the root of my pom but the older versions still get included.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm still not sure what was going on, but I tried creating a new project in Eclipse with the same pom and source files and now the project seems to behave itself.

Answer (score 1):

> Offending resource: ServletContext resource
>   [/WEB-INF/security-context.xml]

Actually the message indicates that `security-context.xml` uses schema/declarations which are incompatible with spring-security-3.1. The message is requesting you to use a 3.0 version of the library instead.  You may want to review and update it and retry.

Comment: Yes, but it shouldn't be because I've been updating jars to 3.1. So I changed the schema declaration to match.

Comment: I need to work out WHY it is complaining, my feeling is because of these 3.0 jars that Maven is including in the build for some reason.